# Django UnicodeDecodeError when using pdb

Tags: django, unicode, pdb

I've notice every time I put an:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

in My Spanish Django project, if I have a specific Unicode character in a string like:

```
Gracias por tu colaboración
```

I get a UnicodeDecodeError with an 'ordinal not in range(128)' in a Django Debug window. The problem is that I can not debug my application easily. On the other hand If I use ipdb I get things like:

```
ERROR - failed to write data to stream: <open file '<stdout>', mode 'w' at 0x7f3d43e34140>
```

I've googled to find a solution, but it looks like I'm the only one having this issue :)

Comment: Does the code work without pdb?

Comment: That is actually what most shocks me, without pdb it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that another programmer had added this to the beginning of the views file, this breaks pdb and ipdb behaviour, as I described:

```
import sys, codecs
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)
```

Removing or commenting these lines fixed the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, that error shows up if you have non-ascii characters in your file (mabe in a comment or a string).
If you try to open it without ipdb/pdb Django will display a traceback